# Html / jquery multiple forms submit

Tags: javascript, html, django

I am working on Django File Sharing Project and in file view  on click on file preview div it will pop-up modal with description of file . I have problems in IDing multiple forms

**FileView.html**

```
<div class="parent">
<div  class="child" onclick="fo()">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="django-script.py">
    <h5 > File.jpg</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="file.jpg">
    <h6 class="title">Image</h6>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/file.png" >
     </form>
</div>

<div  class="child" onclick="fo()">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="django-script.py">
    <h5 > File.pdf</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="file.pdf">
    <h6 class="title">PDF</h6>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/pdf.png" >
     </form>
</div>
<div  class="child" onclick="fo()">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="django-script.py">
    <h5 > File.csv</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="File.csv">
    <h6 class="title">CSV FILE</h6>
    <img class="image" src="/images/icons/file.png" >
     </form>
</div>
</div>
```

script

```
function fo()
{
    document.querySelectorAll(".child")].forEach(child => {
     const forms= child.querySelector(".form")
     forms.submit();
 })
}
```

It works well only for 1 div I dont know how to make it for all div elements

**Original Django Code**
*ViewFile.html*

```
<div class="parent">
 {% for f in file %}

<div  class="child" onclick="fo();">
    <form class="form" method="post" action="{% url 'fileview' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <h5 >{{f.title}}</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="{{f.filename}}">
    <h6 class="title">{{f.filename}}</h6>
    <img class="image" src="{% static '/images/icons/file.png' %}" >
     </form>
</div>

 {% endfor %}

</div>
```

*Views.py*

```
def fileview(request):
     global loginFlag,loginUser
     
     if request.method == 'POST':
         fil=request.POST['file']
         about=Transaction.objects.filter(filename=fil)
         emp=about[0].userid
         aname=Employee.objects.filter(emp_id=emp)[0].name
         print(about)
         files=Transaction.objects.all()
         name=loginName
         context={'files':files,'name':name,'about':about,'aname':aname}
         return render(request,'detailedview.html',context)
     else:    
         file=Transaction.objects.all()
         name=loginName
         context={'file':file,'name':name}
         return render(request, 'viewfile.html',context)
```

I think the issue is in HTML multiple form class. Any solutions will be of great help

Thanks inadvance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your form tags have the same ID (which isn't what you want) and your onclick was instructing JS to submit the first matching ID, hence it was submitting the first form only. Instead make it a relative association. Use a JS function and pass `this` which will refer to the container element. Then in the function find the form inside the element and submit that.

```
<div class="parent">
 {% for f in file %}

<div class="child" onclick="showFile(this)">
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'fileview' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <h5 >{{f.title}}</h5>
    <input type="hidden" name="file" value="{{f.filename}}">
    <h6 class="title">{{f.filename}}</h6>
    <img class="image" src="{% static '/images/icons/file.png' %}" >
     </form>
</div>

 {% endfor %}

<script>
  showFile(div) {
    div.querySelector('form').submit()
  }
</script>
```